# Perl elsif not being evaluated

Tags: perl, string, flow-control

Anyone see anything wrong with this code?  When we execute it (on Linux), we get taken straight to the "Error:  Unknown host" block.

Perl is version 5.8.6

```
$hostname = "host2";

if ($hostname eq "host1") {
  $dbhost = 'dbi:Oracle:dbhost1';
}
elsif ($hostname eq "host2") {
  $dbhost = 'dbi:Oracle:dbhost2';
}
elsif ($hostname eq "host3" || $hostname eq "host4") {
  $dbhost = 'dbi:Oracle:dbhost3';
}
else {
  print "ERROR: UNKNOWN HOST\n";
  die "Can't connect";
}
```

Comment: looks ok to me, and works fine on 5.8.9.  which version of perl are you using?

Comment: Works for me under "This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi" (Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS). What is your exact host, perl version, is this the complete code?

Comment: Are you sure that `$hostname` is defined in your production code?  Are you running with `use warnings; use strict;`?

Comment: Executed fine here, using perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi. Any encoding issues or anything with the text you're testing/comparing to?

Comment: Are you sure `$hostname` doesn't have some extra whitespace?

Comment: Have you stripped your $hostname var of all non visible characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. However, using a lookup table would be simpler (and more flexible):

```
my $driver = 'dbi:Oracle:';
my %dbihosts = (
    host1 => 'dbhost1',
    host2 => 'dbhost2',
    host3 => 'dbhost3',
    host4 => 'dbhost3',
);

my $hostname = "host2";

die "Unknown host '$hostname'" unless exists $dbihosts{ $hostname };

my $dbhost = $dbihosts{ $hostname };
print "$hostname -> $dbhost\n";

$dbh->connect("$driver$dbhost", ...);
```

**PS:** Did you forget to `chomp $hostname`?

Comment: Arggh....the missing chomp was indeed the problem.  However, why does the debugger never show any of the other elsif clauses being evaluated?  It just skips straight to the else.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  It executes as expected for me.

Comment: I'd verify that $hostname is really 'host2' when you think it is.